# Citrix Receiver expand to 2 out of 3 screens?

Tags: display

Is there any way to get Citrix Receiver to use two screens when maximizing when there is a total of three screens?

If I check "Use all displays in full screen" then it will always cover all three screens.

If I try to just position the screen to span over two monitors, it shows on only one and is cut-off at the edge of that monitor.

Is there some magic option I'm missing somewhere? Perhaps a way to fool Citrix into thinking there are only two monitors?

On Windows I can drag the app to the top between two screens and it will maximize to those two screens. Also I can stretch a non-maximized window across screens. That seems not to be the case on my Mac.

Comment: That's a Citrix issue and not an Apple one.  macOS can't (and shouldn't) dictate to an app what window(s)/desktop(s) it needs to occupy.  Unfortunately, there's no magic setting or hidden preference that will enable this - this is at the developer level and how they implement the feature.